# evtest not giving the scan value

Tags: linux, x11, embedded-linux, xorg

I'm using the evtest in my rig to see the KEY value pressed for a button in my hard key remote.Getting the output something liuke this below.

```
***
^[[15~Event: time 1447340367.872317, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN) 
Event: time 1447340367.872329, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 63 (KEY_F5), value 1
Event: time 1447340367.872330, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1447340367.913953, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN) 
Event: time 1447340367.913966, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 63 (KEY_F5), value 0
Event: time 1447340367.913967, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^[[AEvent: time 1447340404.421715, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Event: time 1447340404.421734, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 1
Event: time 1447340404.421735, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1447340404.444706, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Event: time 1447340404.444710, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 0
```

---

The same output in my supplier place is coming as

```
&&&&&&&&&&&
^[[15~Event: time 1447340367.872317, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003e
Event: time 1447340367.872329, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 63 (KEY_F5), value 1
Event: time 1447340367.872330, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1447340367.913953, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003e
Event: time 1447340367.913966, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 63 (KEY_F5), value 0
Event: time 1447340367.913967, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^[[AEvent: time 1447340404.421715, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70052
Event: time 1447340404.421734, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 1
Event: time 1447340404.421735, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1447340404.444706, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70052
Event: time 1447340404.444710, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 0
```

&&&&&&&&&&&

```
^[[15~Event: time 1447340367.872317, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), **value 7003e**
```

The scan value is not coming on my linux rig, any idea how to get that please?

Comment: rig? hard key remote? supplier? Can you be a bit more clearer on the exact configuration or what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JvO, To make it more clear rig is a target (Linux OS based), I am having Bluetooth operated remote controller (sending data via AVRCP profile) which can be paired to my target system and in the putty I can see this log when the evtest is run. When I say supplier he is the third party guy who is pairing a USB emulator HID device and connecting to his linux machine and is getting the second prompt for the same keys pressed, in his log the Key scan value is displayed where as in my target the key scan value is not getting displayed, that is my doubt.how can I see the key scan value in my target

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update the version of evtest on your system. A quick glance at the code of evtest shows that version 1.27 and up always prints the value; earlier versions may not do so.

Comment: I've evtest-1.30-1.1.i586.rpm in my linux target, is there any new version than this, if yes may I know where to download it please?

Comment: Just now checked with evtest-1.31-2.1.3.i586.rpm even then there is no luck of getting the key scan value

Comment: Odd... by the way, isn't the keycode enough? Is there a specific reason you need the scancode?

Comment: Yeah I need this scan code because for few of the HID keys  KEY_PLAYCD ,  KEY_POWER2, KEY_FAVORITES these keys are not available in the standard HID key table (Linux or Windows keyboard) ...These keys are specific to our application (Bluetooth remote) and hence the supplier needs the scan code values to add these keys in his HID mapping.